# Zend framework routing error

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a problem with a routing in Zend framework.

```
'name' => array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/site/:id/orders[/:page]',
        'constraints' => array(
            'id' => '[0-9]*',
            'page'    => '[0-9]*'
        ),
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Site',
            'action'     => 'action'
        ),
    ),
),
```

And in a controller.

```
$id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id');
```

And in some (!) cases a browser returns this error - "Missing parameter 'id'", but I don't know why.

Can anybody help me on this issue?

Comment: *"And in some (!) cases..."* Can you give an example of one of those cases? Otherwise it will be impossible to help you...

Comment: I know it sounds strangely, but it's mainly if the ID consists of only one number. But in some cases, eg. ID 33, it doesn't work as well. I really don't know.

Comment: Can you add these urls as examples to the question?

Answer (score 0):

well based on your route configuration id must exist in your routes, so the link you requested didn't have id . and your constrains also should change to 'id' => '[0-9]+' so the id must exist.

and also you get the id in the controller by just typing

```
$id=$this->params("id");
```

which will get the id too